# Cannot set UUID as Primary Key for a Rails 4 Model in MySQL

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-4, web-applications, model, migration

Been trying to make UUID as a ID Primary key. MySQL does not recognize anything. except if i put an 'execute' command unto the migration; but i don't want to repeat that in every table.

(attempted to make primary key here)

**actor.rb**

```
class Actor < ActiveRecord::Base

  include UUIDHelper
  self.primary_key = 'id'

end
```

(attempted to make primary key here too)

**uuid_helper.rb**

```
module UUIDHelper

  def self.included(base)
    base.before_create :assign_uuid
    base.primary_key = 'id'
  end

  private
  def assign_uuid
    self.id = UUIDTools::UUID.timestamp_create().to_s.downcase if id.blank?
  end

end
```

(works if i do like ' execute alter table... ' but i want to keep it DRY)

**20151028065430_create_actors.rb**

```
class CreateActors < MainMigration
  def change
    create_table :actors, :id => false do |t|
      t.string :id, :limit => 36, primary_key: true, null: false
      t.string :name, :limit => 64, :required => true
      t.string :logo, :limit => 512
    end
  end
end
```

How do i make 'id' a primary key?